# Equivalent of SQL Query with linq

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I search an equivalent with LINQ for this query :

```
SELECT  *
FROM Shapes
ORDER BY ABS(45.403703 - Latitude), ABS(- 71.948638 - Longitude)
```

Someone have an idea? I begin with linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var results = 
    from x in shapes 
    orderby Math.Abs(45.403703 - x.Latitude),
            Math.Abs(- 71.948638 - x.Longitude)
    select x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var result = shapes
    .OrderBy(s => Math.Abs(45.403703 - s.Latitude))
    .ThenBy(s => Math.Abs(-71.948638 - s.Longitude));
```